# Does $ \mu * N $ imply $ \mu^{-1} * N^{-1} $ where $ * $ denotes Dirichlet multiplication?

Tags: number-theory, inverse-function, totient-function, dirichlet-convolution

Quoting from the book *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* by Tom A. Apostol > Section 2.11 (page 37).

> EXAMPLE The inverse of Euler's $ \varphi $ function. Since $ \varphi = \mu * N $ we have $ \varphi^{-1} = \mu^{-1} * N^{-1} $.

How does $ \varphi = \mu * N $ imply $ \varphi^{-1} = \mu^{-1} * N^{-1}$?

Note:

- The asterisk symbol $ * $ denotes Dirichlet multiplication (also known as Dirichlet convolution).
- The function $ \varphi(n) $ denotes Euler's totient function.
- The function $ \mu(n) $ denotes Mobius function.
- The function $ N(n) $ is defined as $ N(n) = n $.

I am unable to find anything in the preceding text that justifies this step. Maybe I missed something? Can someone help me to understand why this step works?

Comment: Dirichlet convolution is commutative and associative. Hence $(\mu \ast N) \ast (\mu^{-1}\ast N^{-1}) = (\mu \ast \mu^{-1}) \ast (N \ast N^{-1})$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Wow! Thanks for the hint. It seems obvious now but I was stuck here for several hours. I thought a textbook would prove every fact before using them or at least mention it and leave the proof as an exercise to the reader. But here this fact was used without any hint or mention. Is it common to do so in math textbooks? Do I need to watch out for such unexplained steps and try to prove them myself?

Comment: To some extent. Things that are considered obvious, or known background material, are often not explicitly mentioned. Of course some things are only obvious if you look from the right angle (this is an instance of that, I'd say), and some readers will have a different background than the author assumes, or occasionally fail to connect their background knowledge to the topic at hand. But that shouldn't happen too frequently.